# Time complexity of reversing a stack with recursion

Tags: recursion, time-complexity

I have tried to find the time complexity of the following code.

```
int insert_at_bottom(int x, stack st) {
if(st is empty) {
    st.push(x)
}
else {
    int a = st.top()
    st.pop()
    insert_at_bottom(x)
    st.push(a)
}
}
void reverse(stack st) {
    if(st is not empty) {
        int st = st.top()
        st.pop()
        reverse(st)
        insert_at_bottom(x, st)
    }
}
// driver function
int[] reverseStack(int[] st) {
    reverse(st)
    return st
}
```

For each element on top of the stack we are popping the whole stack out placing that top element at the bottom which takes O(n) operations. And these O(n) operations are performed for every element in the stack, so time complexity should be O(n^2).

However, I want to find the time complexity mathematically. I tried to find the recurrence relation, and I got T(n)=2T(n-1)+1. This is probably wrong, as the time complexity of the second function call should not be taken as T(n-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argumentation is in general correct. If insertion at the bottom takes *O(n)* time, then the reverse function takes *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* time, because it performs a linear-time operation on the stack for each element.

The recurrence relation for `reverse()` would look a bit different though. In each step, you do three things:

1. Call itself on *n-1*
2. An *O(n)* time operation (`insert_at_bottom()`)
3. Some constant-time stuff

Thus, you can just sum these together. So I would argue it can be written as:

***T(n) = T(n-1) + n + c***, where *c* is a constant.

You will find that, due to recursion, *T(n-1) = T(n-2) + n-1 + c*. So, if you keep expanding the whole series in this fashion under *n > 0*, you obtain:

*T(n) = 1 + ... + n-1 + n + nc*

Since *1 + 2 + ... + n) = n(n + 1)/2* (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)), we obtain that

*T(n) = n(n+1)/2 + nc = n<sup>2</sup>/2 + n/2 + nc = O(n<sup>2</sup>)*. □

The *O(n)* time of `insert_at_bottom()`, you can show in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks, I get it! We won't consider the insert_at_bottom() function to be T(n-1) time complexity but just n. I use the same logic for a for loop.

Comment: You're welcome! You will find that even for `insert_at_bottom`, your loop logic can be proven with a recursive function. It is *T(n) = T(n-1) + c*, where *c* is a constant. You will get *c + c + c... = nc = O(n)*